# with memcache, can you add/remote nodes on the fly?

Tags: memcached

with memcache, can you add/remote nodes on the fly?

if a node goes down, does it redistribute automatically?

Answer (score 3):

Memcached daemons themselves do not have any knowledge of one another. Node management is handled completely at the client level.  Most client implementations rely on [consistent hashing](http://www.mikeperham.com/2009/01/14/consistent-hashing-in-memcache-client/) of keys to determine which server in a ring the values reside on.  Many of the client libraries will failover to other nodes in the ring when a node becomes unavailable.

I am not aware of any memcached clients that attempt to provide clustering or high availability.

Answer (score 2):

No, But you can try [Hazelcast](http://www.hazelcast.com). Also it doesn't state yet with version 1.8.5 it does support memcache protocol. The next release will have all documentation about it.

So you can replace your Memcached servers with Hazelcast. And Hazelcast does support adding and removing nodes on the fly.